# Hover page background change color fade effect (css or jQuery)

Tags: css, css-transitions, background-color

I have tried to figure out to let the background color fade when changing. But fail to do so. Not sure whether I should use css or jQuery. Please have a look, thank you.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.left-col,
.right-col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

a.btn {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.btn:before {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

a.btn:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.btn.btn-1:hover:before {
  background-color: red;
}

a.btn.btn-2:hover:before {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-col">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-1">Button 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-2">Button 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update the jquery fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rae0724/k3bkbpg7/2/
It's working now, but the place that I hover is not accurate.
It keep on showing green even I didn't hover anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background-color is a CSS transitionable/animatable property.

All I did was set the transition, and used JQuery to add/remove some classes causing the background color of that element to change.

Have a look at my CodePen here:
http://codepen.io/jarodsmk/pen/EyAOdN

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Mouse over a color</h1>
  </br>
  <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  <div class="green">Green</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 4s;
}

.blue,body.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.green,body.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.blue').hover(function(){
  $('body').addClass('blue');
}, function(){
  $('body').removeClass('blue');
});

$('.green').hover(function(){
  $('body').addClass('green');
}, function(){
  $('body').removeClass('green');
});
```

Comment: My absolute pleasure! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove css some property from `:hover:before` and add this in `a.btn:before`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.left-col,
.right-col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

a.btn {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.btn:before {
  background-color:transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease,opacity;
  content: '';
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0; 
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0; 
}
a.btn:hover:before {
  position:fixed;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease ,opacity;
  opacity:1; 
}
a.btn.btn-1:hover:before {
  background-color:red;
}   
a.btn.btn-2:hover:before {
  background-color:green; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-col">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-1">Button 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-2">Button 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rae0724/k3bkbpg7/2/ 
It's working now, but the place that I hover is not accurate. It keep on showing green even I didn't hover anything.